# Is it possible to combine user defined type guards in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, casting

Given

```
type Maybe<T> = T | undefined;

class Obj {
    jbo: Maybe<Jbo>;
}
```

, is it possible to define a function that given a `o: Maybe<Obj>` asserts the types of both `o` and `o.jbo`?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
function everythingIsDefined(o: Maybe<Obj>):o is Obj && o.jbo is Jbo {
    // checks in here
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A user-defined typeguard can only return one `x is T`.  Luckily, you can use unions and intersections in your choice of `T`.  So, for example:

```
function everythingIsDefined(o: Maybe<Obj>): o is Obj & {jbo: Jbo} {
    return typeof o !== 'undefined' && typeof o.jbo !== 'undefined';
}
```

The `everythingIsDefined` function asserts that the input is *both* an `Obj` (as opposed to undefined), *and* an object whose `jbo` property is a `Jbo` (as opposed to undefined).  So you can use it like this:

```
if (everythingIsDefined(obj)) {
  console.log(obj.jbo.toString()) // no error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can pull that off:

```
type Maybe<T> = T | undefined;
type DeepMaybe<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Maybe<T[K]> };

class Obj {
    jbo: Jbo;
}

function everythingIsDefined<T>(o: DeepMaybe<T>): o is T {
    return false;
}
```

And then:

```
let obj: DeepMaybe<Obj> = {} as Obj;
if (everythingIsDefined(obj)) {
    // type of obj.jbo is Jbo
} else {
    // type of obj.jbo is Maybe<Jbo>
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Maybe%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0Atype%20DeepMaybe%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20Maybe%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%20%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20Jbo%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Obj%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20jbo%3A%20Jbo%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20everythingIsDefined%3CT%3E(o%3A%20DeepMaybe%3CT%3E)%3A%20o%20is%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20obj%3A%20DeepMaybe%3CObj%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20Obj%3B%0Aif%20(everythingIsDefined(obj))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20obj.jbo%20is%20Jbo%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20obj.jbo%20is%20Maybe%3CJbo%3E%0A%7D))

Explanation:
There's probably no way to acomplish that with the types you provided (that is `Obj.jbo: Maybe<Jbo>`).
Instead, the class `Obj` needs to define its properties as the actual type, but if you type your variable as `DeepMaybe<Obj>` (or anything else instead of `Obj`) then you get the same thing.

The difference is now, because `DeepMaybe` is a mapped type you have better control on how to create the type guard.

Comment: You've changed the type of `Obj.jbo` from `Maybe<Jbo>` to `Jbo`.  Why?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying now.  This is a neat way of dealing with a more general case, although I think the OP's question can be answered more directly.